# h:inputFile doesn't call Part setter

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2.2

This is my first time using h:inputFile and I'm having some trouble.

The setter method for the Part attribute in my Managed Bean is never being called, so when the upload method is called, the Part object is always null.

**Form and inputFile component**

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="pic add-pic">
        <h:inputFile id="upload-test" required="true"
            value="#{uploadController.uploadedFile}">
        </h:inputFile>
        <h:commandLink styleClass="pic add-pic"
            action="#{uploadController.addPic()}">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            <span>Add pic</span>
        </h:commandLink>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

**Managed Bean**

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class UploadController {
    private Part uploadedFile;

    public Part getUploadedFile() {
        return this.uploadedFile;
    }

    public void setUploadedFile(Part uploadedFile) {
        this.uploadedFile = uploadedFile;
    }

    public void addPic() {
        System.out.println("Uploaded a file: " +
            uploadedFile.getSubmittedFileName());
    }
}
```

I've tried already with ajax in the inputFile

```
<h:inputFile id="upload-test" required="true"
    value="#{uploadController.uploadedFile}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" listener="#{uploadController.addPic()}" />
</h:inputFile>
```

and with ajax in the commandLink

```
<h:commandLink styleClass="pic add-pic">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    <span>Add pic</span>
    <f:ajax execute="@form" listener="#{uploadController.addPic()}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

But neither options worked as well.

**PS:** I'm using javax.servlet-api version 3.1 and JSF 2.2.12 (Mojarra) and running on Wildfly 9.0.2

**PS2:** I'm using also Primefaces (not in this case), and I have the fileUpload filter in my web.xml (I've tried to remove it, tested and no success).

Comment: You should not have Servlet API bundled in webapp. You should not have JSF API/impl bundled in webapp. You should not have PrimeFaces FileUploadFilter configured in webapp. Please confirm that you have got rid of them all. When unsure just create a completely empty test project from scratch and do not touch the libraries/defaults.

Comment: Oh, sorry if I made it seems that I had them bundled, I just wanted to show the versions that I'm using, they're not bundled. I've got rid of the PrimeFaces filter and the problem still happens

Comment: Problem is not visible in information provided so far. Sure you aren't nesting forms or are using custom/3rd party filters? Your code works fine when copypasted into a scratch project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several tries and after deploying a fresh project with only the defaults (just like @BalusC said in the comments of my question), **I discovered that the problem was the PrimeFaces FileUploadFilter in web.xml!!**

I got rid of it before, but I don't know why didn't worked that time, could've been some problem with the project deployment refresh provided by Eclipse.

But now I tried again and it worked!

Thanks @BalusC for your help!

Comment: The same here @Diego. Using JSF 2.2 inputFile component I removed my PrimeFaces filter/mapping from web.xml then It's works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks BalusC and Diego Marques! I had a similar problem with my application, which was deployed on Tomcat 8 - the h:inputFile value "Part" setter was never called. Your help pointed me to some of my libraries which had already discovered that my issue was actually a Tomcat setting.

In case it helps to have it included here too, Tomcat (and likely Glassfish)needs the following setting to make it "spec-compliant".

```
<Context allowCasualMultipartParsing="true"
```

https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/issues/136

Instead of doing the above context setting, you can have your bean marked with @MultipartConfig (and @WebServlet).